# display a picture on the dialer in android

Tags: android, image, phone-state-listener

I want my app to display a picture, when an incoming call happens.

What I did so far is to `catch` the `phone state`.

My question is how can I now put an image on the foreground of the dialer?

Here is my snippet:

```
public class reviever extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TAG", "phone is ringing");

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();

    Intent toPop = new Intent(context, PicPop.class);
    toPop.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(toPop);
}}
```

manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".PicPop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">

    </activity>
```

my problem now is that all looks nice, i have a small picture on top of the stock dialer, and the background is translucent, but i cant answer the call.  how can i change it so the picture will stay on top of the dialer but have an interaction with the dialer so to answer a call?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way.  you only need to make the background of the activity transparent 
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" and declare the activity not touchable and show when locked:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

thanks you all any way.

Comment: +1, So does it allow user to touch button placed on In call Screen.  and how do u make sure that it will not hide features like accept or reject call.

Comment: its not, the activity is totally transparent to touch. no metter where you press the activity behind it (the dialer)will receive the touch. even if you press on the image. so, every thing in the activity layout witch is transparent will show the dialer and no metter where you press the dialer receive it.  any thing else you want me to clarify?

Comment: SO... maybe you can help me now... for some reason it works great on all devices except on htc. due to the sense!  do you have any idea why? only in sense the background is not transparent.\

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't. There are lots of things you can customize, including the dialer, but not the incoming/outgoing/during-call screens, for security reasons.

http://kschang.hubpages.com/hub/Full-Android-Customization-Guide-How-to-Change-Almost-Anything-In-Your-Android-Device

Comment: i know i can't change it. but i dont want to.  i want to put a picture on it. like a popup or something.  as an overlay. i know for a fact that it is posible.

Comment: In that case, although you can't launch a popup directly from a BroadcastReceiver, you can launch an Activity, which uses android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" to just show what you want.

Comment: Yes, provide a button for the user to click and then programmatically answer the call. One way is here: http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-answer-incoming-call-in-android.html

Comment: again, i dont want to take over the stock ringer window, i only want to display a small picture on top of if, as a small foreground. how can i do that?

Comment: You could pop up just a dialog box instead of a whole activity, but probably what you want is to display a toast with an image, such as this: http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/02/toast-with-image.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can start An Activity(from phone state receiver) with Picture/ImageView in it, But make sure you have Answer/Reject Button on your custom screen else it will not let user pick/reject the call.

P.S :- Behavior of this thing is different on different devices, Even on the same device it can not override Incall screen some times

Comment: so, you are saying that i cant put an overlay on the original dialer? i dont want to take over the stock ringer screen, i only want to put a small picture on top of it.

Comment: You can not modify in Call screen which is a part of Phone application. What u can do is overlay the screen with ur Activity Screen

Comment: thats exactly what i want to do...  put a small picture on top of the ringer as an overlay..  but how can i do it?

Comment: That what i told u, Start An Activity, But you should have Answer/Reject option on ur screen, or do create Exact same screen like incall. and on that show whatever u want

Comment: just to be clear, you are saying that i cant do that without taking over the ringer?
also, i edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, If u overlay any screen, Below screen features/view can not be accessible. U need to override completely

Comment: i know for a fact that it is possible, i have an application that is doing it. i just want to do the same thing. in that app you can see that the ringer is the original stock one and that the picture is a very simple overlay on top of the dialer.

Comment: Let me know the application then,, If any application non System doing this, I surely will let u know how it is doing then...]

Comment: it sounds weird but i cant send you the app. ill explain. this app is being developed as out sourcing and i cant get the code yet. i only have this component working.  for a business reason i need to do the same thing right now by myself.

Comment: Interesting!! People want to know solutions from others but do not want to share info , Great !! all the best :)

Comment: no... you dont understand!!!  i dont have the code!!   what information you want?! i told you all that i know.  i (we) am not the out sourcing...  we are paying for a different company to develop it for us and they dont want to give us the code yet.  and because i cant wait for this component i want to know how to do it.